# Ошибка в выводе данных exif

Tags: javascript, node.js, gps, exif

Вывести значения в формате `float`. Выдает значения Nan.

```js
var piexif = require("piexifjs");
var fs = require("fs");

var file = "myImage.jpg";
var image = fs.readFileSync(file);
var data = image.toString("binary");
var exifObj = piexif.load(data);

var latRef = piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLatitudeRef === 'N' ? 1 : -1;
var longRef = piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLongitudeRef === 'E' ? 1 : -1;
var lat = exifObj["GPS"][piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLatitude];
var long = exifObj["GPS"][piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLongitude];
var gps = {
    latitude: latRef * (lat[0]+ (lat[1]/60)+(lat[2]/3600)),
    longitude: longRef * (long[0] + (long[1]/60) + (long[2]/3600))
};
console.log(lat);
console.log(gps);
```

Comment: `var piexif = require("piexifjs");` ругается на require(), т. к. его "нет на клиентской стороне", используйте подключение через <script></script>

Comment: его надо установить npm install piexifjs. Проблема именно в параметрах console.log

Comment: но я работаю в консоле

Comment: В терминале зайдите в директорию где лежит файл и выполните node your-filename.js Ошибка у вас не у параметрах console.log, а в том что вы файл запускаете в браузере и он не распознаёт require()

Comment: Да, извините, туплю уже... Я же в браузере его запускаю. Вы бы ошибку хоть указали.
Подстановка происходит с null или ошибка?

Comment: Охх.. С gps работал, но уже и не припомню..  Там что-то вроде этого: `gpsIfd[piexif.GPS.GPSLatitudeRef]` и дальше с ним работать. Вы уверены в структере `exifObj["GPS"]`? дампните объект и будет видно что дальше с ним делать, мне не дает покоя это -> `piexif.TAGS["GPS"]["GPSLongitude"]["longitude"]`

Comment: получилось вывести значение. но теперь моя задача заключается в выводе значения в формате float. при выводе выдает Nan. (исправила код в задании. не могли бы глянуть?)